# Apache ssh proxy domain

Tags: apache, proxy, ssh

I have a vps with my company that I use for various things.

Recently I've been using mutt to check my email, as well as offloading most tasks onto my vps.  I generally ssh into my vps to do these things.  Unfortunately, I've had some issues while doing this while using public WiFi.  It seems as though most public networks, including my schools, do not allow access on ports other than 80 or 443.

I was wondering if there is a way I could set up a subdomain, say remote-ssh.domain.com and use that as my hostname to ssh over port 80/443, and have apache forward it to port 22 on my vps.

Is this something that is possible?  If so, how?
I am open to alternatives as well.